# Mean structure for highly dependent covariates in migration data?

Tags: linear-model, predictor

A group of subjects (animals) travel from position A to position B over a period of 4 months. Every day in these months, a response $y$ has been measured on each subject.

The two main covariates are **Date** and **Position** (longitude and latitude).

From **Date**, we can infer what month it is, what day it is, what week it is, etc.

Since the movement of the animals is of a migratory nature, position is going to be highly dependent on date (in particular "month", since the animals are not constantly moving, but settle at particular positions where they stay for a while, until they move somewhere else, and stay there for a while, etc).

My question is, how should the mean structure in a linear normal regression be modelled for the response $y$, if the interest lies in the influence of date and position on the response $y$? I was thinking something like:

$$y \sim f(day) + month + f(lon,lat)$$

So, we use smooth additive terms to model the influence of day and position, while month enters as a factor.

I would then try to reduce this model using AIC and see whether the dependency of some of the covariates results in us not needing e.g. "day" but only month, or maybe position is unnecessary, since "day" and "month" alone suffice.